# Python creating a list with variable size which contains floating points

Tags: python, list, append

I want to be able to create a 2d list with a variable size.

```
test = [[]]
```

The problem is the data I want to put inside of it is a floating point. This makes it incompatible with the append function

```
                TempData[0] = 1
                TempData[1] = 2.32
                TempData[2] = 3.65
                test.append(float(TempData))
```

Is There any way around this? I don't really want to declare a huge list because sometimes the 2D list size may be very big or very small.

Comment: You can't pass a list to `float()`. Try `test.append(TempData)` since they're already floats.

Comment: What is the final form you want? `test = [[1, 2.32, 3.65]]`? Something else?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm appending arrays on top of each other so the final Data form would be test = [[1, 2.32, 3.65][2.312,1.231,1.111]…….]

Comment: @ggorlen I've tried that, but without declaring a data type the final appended list only contains the value that it saw during the first append like test = [[1, 2.32, 3.65][1, 2.32, 3.65][1, 2.32, 3.65]…..]. I'm unsure of why it shows that behavior.

Comment: @Trubsworth That may be because all your lists are aliases of each other, which has nothing to do with float. What you call "declaring a data type" is a casting operation. You may have done something like `[[]] * 30` somewhere along the way or all your `TempData` lists that you're appending are the same object. Please post a [complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see [x-y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your issue is due to passing an object, TempData to a list and then changing the contents of that object. A reference to TempData is stored in the list, not the values contained in that list. When you alter TempData, it alters every element in the list. Instead, try this:

```
test = []
test.append([1, 2.32, 3.65])
test.append([2.312, 1.231, 1.111])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I'm new to python and I am a pretty novice programmer, so I was unaware of this interaction. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The [python array module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) is made specifically for the purpose of holding numeric values. Here is an example using a list and an `array.array`:

```
import array
mylist = []
mylist.append(array.array('f', [1.43, 1.54, 1.24]))
```